# Restarting a MySQL server managed by Ambari

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I have a scenario where I need to change several parameters of a hadoop cluster managed by Ambari to document performance of a particular application. The change in the configs entails a restart of the affected components.

I am using the [Ambari REST API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Restarting+host+components+via+the+API) for achieving this. I figured out how to do this for all service components of hadoop. I' am not sure whether the API provides a way to restart the MySQL server that Hive uses.

I have the following questions:-

1. Is it the case that a mere stop and start of mysqld on the appropriate machine is enough to ensure that the required configuration changes are recognized by Ambari and the application?
2. I chose the 'New MySQL database' option while installing Hive via Ambari. Does this mean that restarts are reflected in Ambari only when it is carried out from the Ambari UI?

Your inputs would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What configuration changes did you make, and how did you make them? Did you edit config files directly on disk or through the ambari ui? If you edited them on disk which files were modified?

Comment: @cjackson I was changing the minimum and maximum yarn container sizes to limit the total amount of memory allocated to yarn. I was also varying the memory for a task container and number of cpu vcores requested by the tez appMaster. I used the configurations `hive.tez.container.size`, `tez.task.resource.cpu.vcores` and `tez.task.resource.memory.mb`

Comment: Upon further digging of the documentation I found a useful link [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Restarting+host+components+via+the+API). The service name should be HIVE and the component name would be MYSQL_SERVER

Comment: You should update your question with the commands you tried that were wrong. Then add an answer with the correct commands. It may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to the problem. I used the following commands using the Ambari REST API for changing configurations and restarting services from the backend.

Login to the host on which the ambari server is running and use the already provided config.sh script as described below.

### Modifying configuration files

```
#!/bin/bash
CLUSTER_NAME=$1
CONFIG_FILE=$2
PROPERTY_NAME=$3
PROPERTY_VALUE=$4

/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/scripts/configs.sh -port <ambari-server-port> set localhost $1 $2 "$3" "$4"
```

where `CONFIG_FILE` can take values like `tez-site`, `mapred-site`, `hadoop-site`, `hive-site` etc. `PROPERTY_NAME` and `PROPERTY_VALUE` should be set to values relevant to the specified `CONFIG_FILE`.

### Restarting host components

```
curl -uadmin:admin -H 'X-Requested-By: ambari' -X POST -d '
{
   "RequestInfo":{
      "command":"RESTART",
      "context":"Restart MySQL server used by Hive Metastore on node3.cluster.com and HDFS client on node1.cluster.com",
      "operation_level":{
         "level":"HOST",
         "cluster_name":"c1"
      }
   },
   "Requests/resource_filters":[
      {
         "service_name":"HIVE",
         "component_name":"MYSQL_SERVER",
         "hosts":"node3.cluster.com"
      },
      {
         "service_name":"HDFS",
         "component_name":"HDFS_CLIENT",
         "hosts":"node1.cluster.com"
      }
   ]
}' http://localhost:<ambari-server-port>/api/v1/clusters/c1/requests
```

Reference Links:

1. [Restarting components](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Restarting+host+components+via+the+API)
2. [modifying configurations](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Modify+configurations)

Hope this helps!